# Load a popover after page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I've got stuck when i tried to show a bootstrap's popover after my page refresh/reload using `<a></a>` element.

More detailed... I want to show a popover when the user click on logout button, the page reload and after that, i want the popover to be showed.

I've tried to set the URL to `.../index.php?page=index&success`, get the 'success' part of the link if it exists, and show the popover, but it hasn't worked.

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
        var x = location.pathname;
        var parts = x.split('&', 2);

        if(parts[1] == "success")
        {
            $("#popoverLogout").popover({
                content: "Message to be shown",
                html: true,
                placement: 'top',
                trigger: 'manual'
                delay: {'show':1000, 'hide':250},
                container: 'popoverContainer',
            });
        }
    });
```

Any ideas how i can get this work? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After you have created your popover you will need to show it

```
$("#popoverLogout").popover('show');
```

because you have set your trigger to manual.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
var parts = x.split('&', 2);
 if(parts[1] == "success")
```

to

```
var parts = x.split('&');
 if(parts.indexOf('success') > -1)
```

Comment: Still doesn't appear... I think something it's missing, but i don't know why. I haven't put the `#popoverLogout` anywhere, should i put it on the "Log Out" button?

Comment: have you tried $("#popoverLogout").popover('show');

Comment: Yes, I've added it just after the:`$("#popoverLogout").popover({
                content: "Message to be shown",...});`, and it still didn't show...